# integerating twitter,facebook to iphone app using button is not working

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter, ios6, runtime-error

I am trying to integrate Twitter and Facebook into my app.

I tried [this demo](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/), and it works only when I try it in a separate project. When I try it in my project it does not work (the actions do not integrate to the buttons).

It shows this message to me:

> `2013-06-25 11:50:39.885 app[1255:19703] Warning: Attempt to present <SLFacebookComposeViewController: 0xa199280> on <ViewController: 0x9497b60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this link:

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287678/warning-attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hiera)

Quoted from the above link:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
       self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       self.blankviewController = [[blankPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"blankPageViewController" bundle:nil];
       self.window.rootViewController = self.blankviewController;
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is related to the library not to the viewcontroller .When I added Social.framwork target the xcode did not add it Thank you