# Presenting a modal view from a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I checked the various answers here and could not find one which works. I have a regular TabBarController based application. I want to show a login screen at launch. What I did was

- Subclassed UITabBarController and implemented the following in the viewDidAppear:

  LoginViewController *controller = (LoginViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginVC"];
  [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

Once this runs there are 2 things happening : 
1. The login view never shows up
2. The log has this : Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your new subclass set as the window's rootviewcontroller?

Comment: I updated the storyboard to say that the UITabBarController is MyTabBarController. Yes from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : (lldb) po self.window.rootViewController
<MyTabBarController: 0x7f937966fd10>

Comment: Hmnn.. in the story board it says Tab Bar Controller. If I go to the inspector and check the custom class it says MyTabBarController

Comment: Take a look at the solutions presented here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287678/warning-attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hiera/15287859#15287859

Comment: nothing there actually worked.. the only idea i got from there is that the UITabBarController may not be the right place to show the view, as the first view controller in the tabbarcontroller may not be ready, so I moved the code to the first ViewController the TabBarController shows, but that shows :
2014-09-30 16:46:36.753 myapp[45844:3321157] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <FirstViewController: 0x7fc89c81a9e0>.
2014-09-30 16:46:37.329 myapp[45844:3321157] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: 0x7fc89c812c50>.

Comment: I also tried this in the first view controller viewDidLoad     [self.tabBarController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

2014-09-30 16:52:35.173 myapp[45900:3336546] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: 0x7fc2c24718b0>.

Comment: Try doing it in viewDidAppear with no animation, and that modal view controller should be the first thing the user sees.

Answer (score 0):

rdelmar answer fixed the warning, that is do the presentation in the viewDidAppear. Thanks!