# UINavigation Controller inside the UITabBar Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

I'm using [PEPhotoCropEditor](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor) inside a UITabBar controller. When i choose image for cropping. its working fine with iOS 8.0. But when i crop the image from iOS 6.1 i'm getting the following error

[image]

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x201cc5f0> on <UITabBarController: 0x2013a3f0> while a presentation is in progress!
```

Can anyone please any solution to perform image crop inside the Tabbar controller under iOS 6.1 and above

Answer (score 1):

May be you are presenting another controller while a view controller is going to present.
Try  [self performSelector:@selector(yourNewFunction) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

Follow these Links -

[Warning: attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287678/warning-attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hiera/15287859#15287859)

[Warning: Attempt to present ModalTableViewController on MainTableViewController which is already presenting (null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213152/warning-attempt-to-present-modaltableviewcontroller-on-maintableviewcontroller)